# How to multi thread and do tasks in django?

Tags: django, data-science, multitasking, calculation

I am working on a website based on Django. users can register and enter a URL, and my website should check and get some information from that URL, for example, every hour, how should I handle these tasks? how should I write the structure of my website?

specifically, there's a function, that will get some data from an API.
I want my website, to get user's ID for that API, and refresh every user's data every hour.

Comment: Please ask a specific, detailed question for a problem you have. Your's is a general question, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I added some details.